# Is there a way to get the name of processes killed using taskkill /f /fi "status eq not responding"?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm aware we can use **tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq *pid_number*"**, but is there a way to include this in taskkill ??

Answer (score 1):

Would this be enough?

```
tasklist /svc /fi "status eq not responding"
taskkill /f /fi "status eq not responding"
```

So first - enumerate processes by condition, then stop them using the same condition

Comment: Not really, how does that provide the names of the services killed? It tells you what was unresponsive, that's it! The only way is to parse a list of unresponsive processes, get some unique information about each, _(PID)_, kill them, acting on the errorlevel, and checking the status of each process using the information you had which was unique to it.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Thanks, lads